# pandas dataframe, copy by value

Tags: python, pandas

I noticed a bug in my program and the reason it is happening is because it seems that pandas is copying by reference a pandas dataframe instead of by value. I know immutable objects will always be passed by reference but pandas dataframe is not immutable so I do not see why it is passing by reference. Can anyone provide some information?

Thanks!
Andrew

Answer (score 41, accepted):

All functions in Python are "pass by reference", there is no "pass by value". If you want to make an explicit copy of a pandas object, try `new_frame = frame.copy()`.

Comment: Note that this does not include the `frame.index` as of version 0.12. However, a fix seems to be on the way for 0.13 (as mentioned in [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17591104/2375855): GitHub Pandas [Issue 4202](http://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4202))