# In pandas, can I deeply copy a DataFrame including its index and column?

Tags: python, pandas

First, I create a DataFrame

```
In [61]: import pandas as pd
In [62]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1], [2], [3]])
```

Then, I deeply copy it by `copy`

```
In [63]: df2 = df.copy(deep=True)
```

Now the `DataFrame` are different.

```
In [64]: id(df), id(df2)
Out[64]: (4385185040, 4385183312)
```

However, the `index` are still the same.

```
In [65]: id(df.index), id(df2.index)
Out[65]: (4385175264, 4385175264)
```

Same thing happen in columns, is there any way that I can easily deeply copy it not only values but also index and columns?

Comment: `deep=True` is the default btw

Answer (score 26):

Latest version of Pandas does not have this issue anymore

```
  import pandas as pd
  df = pd.DataFrame([[1], [2], [3]])

  df2 = df.copy(deep=True)

  id(df), id(df2)
  Out[3]: (136575472, 127792400)

  id(df.index), id(df2.index)
  Out[4]: (145820144, 127657008)
```

Comment: @LoremIpsum, do you mean to imply that the bug has not returned in those releases dated to 2017? Sergey's answer from 2014 implies it was fixed by then. The comment could be a stronger one if the bug had resurfaced in those versions of the library!!

Answer (score 11):

I wonder whether this is a bug in pandas... it's interesting because Index/MultiIndex (index and columns) are in some sense [supposed to be immutable](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/4039) (however I think these should be copies).

For now, it's easy to create your own method, and add it to DataFrame:

```
In [11]: def very_deep_copy(self):
    return pd.DataFrame(self.values.copy(), self.index.copy(), self.columns.copy())

In [12]: pd.DataFrame.very_deep_copy = very_deep_copy

In [13]: df2 = df.very_deep_copy()
```

As you can see this will create new objects (and preserve names):

```
In [14]: id(df.columns)
Out[14]: 4370636624

In [15]: id(df2.columns)
Out[15]: 4372118776
```