# When I shuffle a copy of a DataFrame, why the original DataFrame is also shuffled?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, random

Here is the input,

```
    df1= pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,3), columns= list("ABC") )
              A         B         C
    0  0.468682 -0.136178  0.418900
    1 -0.362995 -0.111931  0.433537
    2 -1.194483 -0.844683 -1.022719
    3  0.531893 -1.032088 -1.683009
    4  2.113807 -0.450628  0.004971
    5  0.141548 -0.621090 -0.135580
    6  0.128670 -0.460494 -0.016550
    7 -0.099141 -0.010140 -0.066042
    8  1.317759 -1.522207 -0.234447
    9 -0.039051 -1.395751 -0.431717
```

Then I create a copy of it. I assume I actually cloned the object not just creating a new link to it. I want to shuffle the copy of the original DataFrame while keep the original one untouched.

```
    df2=df1.copy(deep= True)
```

After I shuffled the df2,by doing this

```
    np.random.shuffle(df2.index.values)
```

Then I found both df2 and df1 are shuffled.

```
    df1.index
    Out[177]: Int64Index([7, 8, 0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 2, 5, 9], dtype='int64')

    df2.index
    Out[178]: Int64Index([7, 8, 0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 2, 5, 9], dtype='int64')
```

Someone says it is caused by the Deep Copy being not actually deep. Then I try to see whether the index of each DataFrame refers to different objects. 
I tried,

```
    print(id(df1.index))
    print(id(df2.index))
    df1.index is df2.index
```

I have,

```
    156017776
    156170112
    False
```

Now I am even more confused. If they are different objects, why my solution failed and how to achieve what I want ?
This is not a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591104/in-pandas-can-i-deeply-copy-a-dataframe-including-its-index-and-column) because at that time deep copy does not create a new index object but now the copy does have a new index object.Yet, the problem is still there.
(I am using pandas 0.17.0; numpy 1.10.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDs of `df1.index` and `df2.index` are different but `df1.index.values` and `df2.index.values` have the same ID:

```
In [68]: id(df1.index), id(df2.index)
Out[68]: (140032214366920, 140032214391720)

In [69]: id(df1.index.values), id(df2.index.values)
Out[69]: (140032213182304, 140032213182304)
```

[`np.random.shuffle`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) changing values inplace, so you could use [`np.random.permutation`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html) and assign to `df2.index` result:

```
In [73]: df2.index = np.random.permutation(df2.index)

In [74]: df1.index
Out[74]: Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype='int64')

In [75]: df2.index
Out[75]: Int64Index([6, 2, 1, 8, 7, 0, 4, 5, 3, 9], dtype='int64')
```

But it still strange why `df1.index` and `df2.index` have different IDs but their values not.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, your findings are consistent with results I have tested.

I found this online https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4202

It seems that in pandas, date frame copy will exclude index (df.index will not be deep copied)

A possible fix I tried as following:

```
df1= pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,3), columns= list("ABC") )
print df1.index
df2=df1.copy(deep= True)
df2.index = copy.deepcopy(df1.index)
np.random.shuffle(df2.index.values)
print df1.index
```

results as following:

```
Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype='int64')
Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype='int64')
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Why do you think you solve the problem ? When you print df1.index the sequence is still changed, it is [0, 6, 3, 4, 7, 5, 8, 9, 1, 2]. However, I want the df1 to stay the same.

Comment: @PeterLi yes your are right. I think I copied the wrong line. It would be fixed by df2.index = copy.deepcopy(df1.index)