# Functions of pandas data frames and side effects

Tags: python, function, pandas

I want to write a function that takes as input a Pandas data frame and returns the only the rows with an average greater than some specified threshold.  The function *works*, but it has a side effect of changing the input, which I don't want to do.

```
def Remove_Low_Average(df, sample_names, average_threshold=30):
    data_frame = df
    data_frame['Mean'] = np.mean(data_frame[sample_names], axis=1)
    data_frame = data_frame[data_frame.Mean > 30]
    return data_frame.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Example:

```
In [7]: junk_data = DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,5), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
In [8]: Remove_Low_Average(junk_data, ['a', 'b', 'c'], average_threshold=0)
In [9]: junk_data.columns
Out[9]: Index([u'a', u'b', u'c', u'd', u'e', u'Mean'], dtype='object')
```

So junk_data now has 'Mean' in its columns even though this was never assigned in the function.  I realize I could do this in a simpler manner, but this illustrates a problem I've been having regularly I can't figure out why.  I figure that this has to be a well-known thing, but I don't know how to get this side effect to stop happening.

**EDIT**:  EdChum's link below answers the question.

Comment: What did you expect this line to do: `data_frame['Mean'] = np.mean(data_frame[sample_names], axis=1)`? if you just wanted to calculate a local variable then why not just `mean = np.mean(data_frame[sample_names], axis=1)`?

Comment: @EdChum  This is a minimal example that illustrates a problem that I am having with a larger function.  I *expect* that because I am addressing the variable data_frame (which is not passed to the function) that it would leave df (which is) unchanged.  Clearly, that is not the case.  I am wondering why, what this is called, and how to work around it, and where in the Pandas docs I might read more about it.

Comment: Well you have to understand that you are most likely taking a view of the dataframe so any form of assigning will affect the original dataframe, in your example it seems completely unneceessary to create a new column for this calculation.

Comment: @EdChum I agree, but in another function I need to take a data frame and compute various statistics and append those to the output, but I can't do that without changing the original it seems.  This illustrates the kind of things I need to do.

Comment: @EdChum
What do you mean by taking a view of the data frame and why does it mean that any form of assigning will affect the original?  This sounds like exactly what I need to know about.

Comment: It depends on what you're doing but your example doesn't represent your problem as it's not a problem in that example, you could just return `df[np.mean(df[sample_names],axis=1) > 30]`

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419822/pandas-dataframe-copy-by-value so basically if you want to avoid modifying the original then perform a deep copy by calling `.copy()`

Comment: @EdChum Thanks for the link! That's exactly what I needed to see. I didn't know about the pass-by-reference/pass-by-value distinction. Thanks for helping me learn something new today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@EdChum answered this in the comments:

> see [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419822/pandas-dataframe-copy-by-value) so basically if you want to avoid modifying the original then perform a deep copy by calling .copy()

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to copy the old dataframe, just don't assign a new column :)

```
def remove_low_average(df, sample_names, average_threshold=30):
    mean = df[sample_names].mean(axis=1)
    return df.ix[mean > average_threshold]

# then use it as:
df = remove_low_average(df, ['a', 'b'])
```