# Creating new DataFrame from existing dataframe without missing values

Tags: python, pandas

I stuck with quite obvious task.

I have a df with missing data. For processing such kind of data I want to test two dataFrames.

For the first one `X_real_zeros` - I replace missing with 0.
And for the second one `X_real_means` - with column's mean.

I have collected all numeric columns name in one array

```
numeric_cols = ['RFCD.Percentage.1', 'RFCD.Percentage.2', 'RFCD.Percentage.3', 
                'RFCD.Percentage.4', 'RFCD.Percentage.5',
                'SEO.Percentage.1', 'SEO.Percentage.2', 'SEO.Percentage.3',
                'SEO.Percentage.4', 'SEO.Percentage.5',
                'Year.of.Birth.1', 'Number.of.Successful.Grant.1', 'Number.of.Unsuccessful.Grant.1']
```

Then I'm trying to create two dataFrames.

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
X_real_zeros = data
for col in numeric_cols:
    X_real_zeros[col] = data[col].fillna(0)

X_real_means = data
a = calculate_means(data[numeric_cols])
for col in numeric_cols:
    print(a[col], col)
    X_real_means[col] = data[col].fillna(a[col])
```

But, when I want to create the second one, it turns out, that my `data` data frame has been modified. Anyway I think my approach is not accurate, what is the proper way of solving such tasks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use

```
X_real_means = data.copy()
```

Otherwise, the variable `X_real_means` will reference exactly the same object as `data`.

[Wes Mickenny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/776560/wes-mckinney) answered a similar question in here: [pandas dataframe, copy by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419822/pandas-dataframe-copy-by-value)

---

The overall code after the change will look like this:

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
X_real_zeros = data.copy()
for col in numeric_cols:
    X_real_zeros[col] = data[col].fillna(0)

X_real_means = data.copy()
a = calculate_means(data[numeric_cols])
for col in numeric_cols:
    print(a[col], col)
    X_real_means[col] = data[col].fillna(a[col])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think thats all you needed to do:

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
X_real_zeros = data.copy()
for col in numeric_cols:
    X_real_zeros[col] = data[col].fillna(0)

X_real_means = data.copy()
a = calculate_means(data[numeric_cols])
for col in numeric_cols:
    print(a[col], col)
    X_real_means[col] = data[col].fillna(a[col])
```