# Why does a function overwrite another dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df_KO` with the following columns:

`Date`, `Reg` (Registration Number) and a measure of the quality of this particular component (`Status`).

For a certain use, I want to replace the values of these measurements with either *KO* or *OK* depending on a certain threshold with the function:

```
df_KO.Status = df_KO.apply(lambda row: replace_func(row["Status"]), axis=1)
```

Where replace_func is:

```
def replace_func(value):
    if value < 0.25:
        return "OK"
    elif value >= 0.25:
        return "KO"
    else:
        return np.nan
```

However, I also want to keep the original measurement values, so I have made a copy of the DF. But to my surprise the following statement:

```
df_KO_raw = df_KO
df_KO_raw["Reg"] = "Dummy"
print(df_KO_raw.head(5))
df_KO.Status = df_KO.apply(lambda row: replace_func(row["Status"]), axis=1)
print(df_KO_raw.head(5))
```

Gives the following output:

```
                 Date    Reg      Status
0 2017-02-02 11:52:37  Dummy           0
1 2017-02-04 03:02:57  Dummy           0
2 2017-01-27 12:50:53  Dummy  0.00406572
3 2017-01-29 10:58:50  Dummy  0.00754577
4 2017-01-31 22:43:44  Dummy   0.0037902
                 Date    Reg Status
0 2017-02-02 11:52:37  Dummy     OK
1 2017-02-04 03:02:57  Dummy     OK
2 2017-01-27 12:50:53  Dummy     OK
3 2017-01-29 10:58:50  Dummy     OK
4 2017-01-31 22:43:44  Dummy     OK
```

Why is this happening? I'm clearly trying to perform an operation on only the `df_KO DF`, why does it change the values in `df_KO_raw` as well? Oh it has also changed the values of `df_KO`.

I'm probably overlooking something obvious, but at this point I can't really see what. Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: Problem is with `df_KO_raw = df_KO`, need `df_KO_raw = df_KO.copy()` for new object.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on why this is? If I would do this:
    test = 5
    test_2 = test
    test = test*2
This logic does not hold right?

Comment: What about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13420016/2901002) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4794244/2901002)

Comment: @Jeff  this is just python in general, and not specific only to pandas.  when you say `x = y` in python (dataframe or not), they essentially become the same thing (or more accurately, pointers to the same thing).  Just play around with this and test with both `x==y` and `x is y` and you'll get the hang of it.  If you are coming to python from another language, this may be different than what you are used to but it's basically standard python behavior.