# Why the inserted new column to a copied dataframe will be added to the original dataframe too?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Could you please let me know why the new column `c` is added to the original dataframe i.e., `df_old`?

```
df_old = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]})
df_new=df_old
df_new['c']=[5,6]
print('Old:')
print(df_old)
print('New:')
print(df_new)
```

Output:

```
Old:
   a  b  c
0  1  3  5
1  2  4  6
New:
   a  b  c
0  1  3  5
1  2  4  6
```

In fact, I need to preserve the original dataframe as it was:

```
   a  b  
0  1  3  
1  2  4
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: This will be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419822/pandas-dataframe-copy-by-value

Comment: Nice catch.  I'm marking it a dup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html#pandas-dataframe-assign) which creates a copy of the old dataframe:

```
df_old = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]})
df_new = df_old.assign(c=[5,6])
print(df_old)
print(df_new)
```

Output:

```
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
   a  b  c
0  1  3  5
1  2  4  6
```

Comment: This is distinct information from Wes's post.  Deleting mine (-: